# Cassandra node running out of space

Tags: linux, memory, cassandra, jvm, hints

My cassandra linux node ran out of space in /mnt/data/cassandra. When i try to run nodetool it fails because it has no space. I see commitlog, hints, data, saved_caches. Any ideas on clearing up space without nodetool?

Comment: can you SSH into the linux machine? If so can you add space to the /mnt/data/cassandra. If you are just looking to clean up the entire data, you could do "rm -rf *" on /mnt/data/cassandra. You could clean up saved_caches to gain some space, but I don't think it would be sufficient to do the job.

Comment: Which dir you are trying to clean? For commit log: you can use JMX.